# Scala - copy case class with dynamic fields. Is it possible?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, copy, case-class

**Considering a case class that has a default field calculated at creating time, is it possible to copy it where the new copied case class has this field recalculated?**

For example, `TestCopy.auto` is generated at creation time:

```
  case class TestCopy(static: String, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    val auto2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }
```

If I copy it changing only the field `static`:

```
    val a = TestCopy(static = "a")
    val b = a.copy(static = "b")
```

The field `auto` is not recalculated. Neither is the constructor field `auto2`:

```
> println(a)
> println(b)
> println(a.auto2)
> println(b.auto2)

TestCopy(a,1640773176392)
TestCopy(b,1640773176392)
1640773176392
1640773176392
```

It makes sense, actually, since I am copying the case class. **However, I wanted a behaviour similar to recreating the case class, where I change only a set of static fields.** The example above is simplified, I could have just created it again. The question is aiming at cases like:

```
  case class TestCopy2(static1: String,
                       static2: String,
                       static3: String,
                       auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis())
```

**Where only `static1` must be changed, `static2` and `static3` must be copied, and `auto` must be generated again.
Is it possible?**

Thank you all.

Comment: What do you think `val` means? Are there any other alternative keywords that can give it a different behaviour? Does it make sense for it to be a field then, when fields in a `case class` are suppose to be immutable values but you want it to be constantly changing?

Comment: For this usage, you'll have to go with manually instantiating a fresh new instance each time, `copy` won't help. You might create a custom `apply` method though.

Comment: @GaëlJ I wasn't too sure what the question was trying to do but a custom `apply` would make most sense.

Comment: @yangzai, sure we can use var for mutable variables. But the question is about copying case classes to new ones.

Comment: @YFI I'm not talking about `var`

Comment: @YFI the keyword relates to recomputation and `apply`.

Comment: Thanks, @yangzai. Can you be more explicit, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transient values don't get copied automatically:

```
case class Foo(a: Int) { 
   @transient val b: Long = System.currentTimeMillis 
}


val f1 = Foo(1)
Thread.sleep(1000)
val f2 = f1.copy(2)

assert f1.b != f2.b
```

Comment: why this work? Transient is for telling the compiler to not serialize the val. So why in copy is it calculated again?

Comment: @YFI evidently, it is also for telling `copy` not to copy :) It's just how it is. Personally, to me, it kinda make sense that the result of copy is the same as that of serialize/deserialize.

Comment: Get you, @Dima. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A custom `apply` method is viable, but you should also be able to leverage the `abstract case class` trick:

```scala
abstract case class TestCopy(static: String, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()) {
  def copy(static: String = static, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): TestCopy =
    new TestCopy(static, auto)
}

object TestCopy {
  def apply(static: String, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): TestCopy =
    new TestCopy(static, auto)
}
```

Making the `case class` `abstract` suppresses the auto-generated `apply` and `copy` methods.  In this case, the auto-generated `apply` is basically exactly what the compiler would generate.  The generated `copy` would normally be something like

```scala
def copy(static: String = static, auto: Long = auto): TestCopy
```

Note that `auto` defaults to the previous value, so that's the behavior we want to change, thus we define a custom `copy` method to replace the compiler-generated one.

One of the defaults for `auto` can be eliminated by making the constructor private; since `case class`es are not typically instantiated with `new`, this isn't much of a loss:

```scala
abstract case class TestCopy private (static: String, auto: Long) {
  def copy(static: String = static, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): TestCopy =
    new TestCopy(static, auto)
}

object TestCopy {
  def apply(static: String, auto: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): TestCopy =
    new TestCopy(static, auto)
}
```

Now you can:

- create with default current time: `TestCopy("foo")`
- create with preset time: `TestCopy("foo", 0)`
- copy with current time: `TestCopy("foo").copy(static = "bar")`
- copy with preset time: `TestCopy("foo").copy(auto = 0)`

Comment: Have not actually tried this: I normally only use `abstract case class` with `sealed` so I might have the decomposition of what `sealed` and `abstract` do with `case class`es wrong.